# Median of distribution and interpretation given context of the problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, statistics

The time spent waiting between events is sometimes modeled using the exponential distribution. For example, suppose that for a given movie, the number of days in advance that customers can purchase their tickets can be modeled by an exponential distribution with an average advance purchase time of 2 days. Let $T$ be the amount of advance purchase time for customers. Then $T$ is a continuous random variable with the cumulative distribution function $F_t(t)=1-e^{-\frac{t}{2}}$. Determine the median of this distribution, and interpret the value in terms of the context of the scenario provided in the prompt.

effort:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
.5= & 1-e^{-\frac{t}{2}}\\
\implies e^{-\frac{t}{2}}=& .5\\
\implies \frac{t}{2}=& -\ln(.5)\\
\implies t= &2\ln(2)
\end{split}
\end{equation}

So $2\ln(2)$ days is the median.

Interpretation:The median time of waiting for the event after paying for the ticket at time $T$ is given by $2\ln2=1.3863$ days.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

$2\ln(2)$ is correct, for exponential distribution, the median is $\ln2$ times the mean.

Comment: What about the interpretation?

Comment: looks fine too.